# Bootstrap collapse with show parameter not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm playing around with Bootstrap 4 collapse in this very basic trial page: https://lucvandenelschen.github.io/Carla/. In the mobile view, I want the menu which is shown when the hamburger button is clicked, to remain visible after one of the menu items is clicked. I know it should always hide when something is clicked, but I'm testing/learning. The HTML is:

```
                  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsable-nav" aria-controls="collapsable-nav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                </button>
            
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsable-nav">
                    <ul id="nav-list" class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                     <li>
                         <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                            <i class="fas fa-home " aria-hidden="true" id="home-icon-sm-nodisp"></i>
                            <img src="Blender_logo/logo_50.jpg" class="d-md-none" width="50" height="50">
                            <br class="d-none d-md-block">Home</a>
                     </li>
                     <!--li>
                         <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                           <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i><br class="d-none d-md-block"> Bestellen</a>
                     </li-->
                     <li>
                         <a href="#contact" class="nav-link">
                           <i class="fas fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i><br class="d-none d-md-block"> Contact</a>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                         <a href="#contact" class="nav-link">
                            <i class="fas fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i><br class="d-none d-md-block"> Reviews</a>
                     </li>

                     <li class="d-none d-md-block">
                         <a href="https://www.facebook.com/CarlasNailcorner" target="_blanc" class="nav-link">
                           <i class="fab fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="d-none d-md-block">
                         <a href="https://twitter.com/carla_switsers" target="_blanc" class="nav-link">
                           <i class="fab fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="d-none d-md-block">
                         <a href="https://www.instagram.com/switserscarla/" target="_blanc" class="nav-link">
                           <i class="fab fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                     </li>

                     <li class="d-md-none">
                        <nav class="navbar navbar-light justify-content-center" id="social-sm">
                            <div>
                             <a href="https://www.facebook.com/CarlasNailcorner" target="_blanc" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fab fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            </div>
                            <div>                               
                             <a href="https://twitter.com/carla_switsers" target="_blanc" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fab fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            </div>
                            <div>                               
                             <a href="https://www.instagram.com/switserscarla/" target="_blanc" class="nav-link">
                               <i class="fab fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            </div>                     
                         </nav>                                                    
                     </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
```

The Jquery part is:

```
$(function () { // Same as document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"...

 // Same as document.querySelector("#navbarToggle").addEventListener("blur",...
 $(".navbar-toggler").blur(function (event) {
   var screenWidth = window.innerWidth; //With of the browser window itself.
   if (screenWidth < 768) {
     $("#collapsable-nav").collapse('hide'); //collapse is een functie in bootstrap.js, hetgeen JQuery is.
     console.log('test2');
   }
 });

 // In Firefox and Safari, the click event doesn't retain the focus
 // on the clicked button. Therefore, the blur event will not fire on
 // user clicking somewhere else in the page and the blur event handler
 // which is set up above will not be called.
 // Refer to issue #28 in the repo.
 // Solution: force focus on the element that the click event fired on
 // Moet dat hieronder niet .navbar-toggler zijn?
 $("#navbarToggle").click(function (event) {
   $(event.target).focus();
 });
 
 $(".navbar-collapse a").click(function(event){
   console.log('test');
   $("#collapsable-nav").collapse('show');
 });

});
```

I thought this last line  `$("#collapsable-nav").collapse('show');` would cause the menu to stay on the screen when an item is clicked, but that's not happening. In the console you can see that when you click a menu item, first the blur event which contains `console.log('test2');` , is fired. This is hiding the menu when you click elsewhere in the document and the button looses focus.
After that, there's the click event for the menu item, which contains `console.log('test');` , but `$("#collapsable-nav").collapse('show');` doesn't seem to be executed, as the menu is always hiding after clicking a menu item. Any idea why this is happening and how I could make the menu remain visible? I know it makes no sense, the menu should always hide when an item is clicked, but as I said, I'm testing with it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.
But is only a fast solution

```
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
        if (screenWidth < 768) {
          $("#collapsable-nav").collapse('hide');
        }
    })

 
    $(".navbar-toggler").click(function(event){
            $("#collapsable-nav").collapse('show');
        });
  
    // a little hack based on ur container.class
    $(".container-fluid").click(function() {
        $("#collapsable-nav").collapse('hide');
    });
```

Comment: It's even doing what I wanted without 

`$(".navbar-toggler").click(function(event){
            $("#collapsable-nav").collapse('show');
        });`
 
Thank you, but I'm even more confused now :-)

Comment: Any idea why the click event on the container-fluid class is always fired, even when I click in the footer part which is not container-fluid?

Comment: Thats because your footer is inside in the div with class container-fluid. ;)
The clickFunction is for all HTML-Elements with class container-fluid. 
You can: <div class="container-fluid nameYourClickClass"> and
$(".nameYourClickClass").click(..........
Now is not for all container-fluid classes.

Comment: My god, that's co silly. Didn't see it because there's a closing div missing after my footer closing. Thanks. But do you have an idea why my `$(".navbar-collapse a").click(function(event){
   console.log('test');
   $("#collapsable-nav").collapse('show');
 });` isn't working? The 'test' is printed in the console, but the #collapsable-nav is hiding.